# Wkhtmltopdf version, first page and TOC

Tags: pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf

Some questions for this very nifty tool, unfortunately lacking many usage examples.

1. Manual speaks of a possible “Reduced Functionality” for wkhtmltopdf. I have version `wkhtmltox-0.11.0_rc1-installer.exe`, by running `wkhtmltopdf --version`  what should I read to understand whether my version is the reduced one or not?
2. Currently I like wkhtmltopdf for webpages I want to read later and/or store. To mirror webpages I use httrack, then I generate the PDF with `wkhtmltopdf *.html  offline.pdf`. How can I set/specify the first PDF page from the *.html list? Currently they seem to be converted in alphabetical order.
3. If I run `wkhtmltopdf toc http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html qstring.pdf` I simply get a leading blank page, no TOC. What’s wrong?

Thanks for helping

### EDIT:

@Nenotlep:

Your TOC trick works perfectly.

As for the first page, I don’t need an actual cover. 
What I need is a way to download/convert a given page www.site.com/foo.html and all the linked pages (A.html, B.html ...) *up to a certain depth level*. Then I want a single PDF starting with foo.html and containing also the pages A.html, B.html ... (with relative links).

I don’t think there is an option to download and insert the linked pages in the final PDF (please, correct me if I am wrong). So I use `httrack.com` to download and wkhtmltopdf to convert. Given the alphabetical behaviour of wkhtmltopdf, the best now seems to rename the target page, downloaded with httrack, something like `!foo.html`. 
Please, let me know of possible alternatives.

Comment: Your idea is very interesting but sadly I don't really have any other suggestion other than what you already have. If I think of something I'll add here later!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For part 3 of the question which is blank TOC, the latest stable version 0.12.5 also does not generate it. The [pre-release version 0.12.6-dev](https://builds.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12.6-dev/) has fixed this problem in Mac.

Answer (score 4):

1. I think all available precompiled wkhtmltopdf's are compiled with the patched QT, they are not reduced. The reduced functionality means that it was compiled without a special patched version of QT. I use the windows version and it isn't reduced.
2. I think the `cover` command line argument would work for you. I can't test at the moment, but try a command like `wkhtmltopdf cover derpy.html toc --xsl-style-sheet default.xsl rarity.html twilight.html spike.html equestriadaily.pdf`

   At least in Linux, I think the asterix *.html simply explodes into all the html files before the command is performed, so if you select one html file for the cover and then do *.html in the same folder you will get the file twice. Getting around this issue might need some command line sorcery or a batch file or some other trickery.
3. This is a [bug in wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=460). The workaround is to manually set a tocfile. You can get the default tocfile with `wkhtmltopdf.exe --dump-default-toc-xsl`. Then you can save the output as a file and use it like `wkhtmltopdf.exe toc --xsl-style-sheet default.xsl www.stackoverflow.com so.pdf`.